# why my function is not working in php while loop?

Tags: php

I have review function which I need to run in PHP `while` loop. But somehow it's not working if I call the function in while loop.

But If I manually put the code (Rating Function) in while then it's working. Can you tell me why ?

Here is the function code:

```
function rating($star) {
    echo "<div class='my_all_star'>";
    $total = "";
    for ($i=1; $i <= $star; $i++) { 
        $total .= "<img src='../images/star.png'/> ";
    }
    for ($i=1; $i <= (5 - $star); $i++) { 
        $total .= "<img src='../images/star_null.png'/> ";
    }
    if($star > 1 ){
        $reviews = " Reviews";
    }else{ 
        $reviews = " Review";
    }
    $total .= ($star) . $reviews;
    return $total;
    echo "</div>";
}
```

Update : While Loop:

```
<?php
$grq =  mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT tbl_reviews.*, tbl_users.FName, tbl_users.LName FROM tbl_reviews LEFT JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_reviews.reviewerID = tbl_users.UserID WHERE tbl_reviews.ProductID = '$pid' ");

while($allreviews = mysqli_fetch_array($grq)){

$review_text = inputvalid($allreviews['ReviewText']);
$review_date = inputvalid($allreviews['ReviewDate']);
$st_rating = (int) $allreviews['StarRating'];
$fname = inputvalid($allreviews['FName']);
$lname = inputvalid($allreviews['LName']);

      ?>
      <div class="single_main_reviews">
        <div class="col-sm-2 text-center rev_author_info">
          <img src="../images/avater-1.png" alt="" />
          <p>Reviewed by</p>
          <a href=""><?php echo $fname ." ". $lname; ?></a>

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 rev_author_content">
          <div class="rev_author_content_head">
            <div class="">
              <?php 
               echo "<div class='my_all_star'>";
$total = "";
$star =  $st_rating;
for ($i=1; $i <= $star; $i++) { 
    $total .= "<img src='../images/star.png'/> ";
}
for ($i=1; $i <= (5 - $star); $i++) { 
    $total .= "<img src='../images/star_null.png'/> ";
}
if($star > 1 ){
    $reviews = " Reviews";
}else{ 
    $reviews = " Review";
}
$total .= ($star) . $reviews;
echo  $total;
echo "</div>"; 

               ?>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right"><span class="review-date"><?php echo $review_date; ?></span></div>
          </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <p><?php echo $review_text; ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php 
}

?>
```

Comment: Please add the code with while loop, where and how you have used it

Comment: 1) Where's while loop over here ? 2)Might be your question doesn't support SO specifications but can be placed over http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Replace return with echo

Comment: `return` and `echo` in same function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont echo and return data at the same time.

```
function rating($star) {
    $total =  "<div class='my_all_star'>";

    for ($i=1; $i <= $star; $i++) { 
        $total .= "<img src='../images/star.png'/> ";
    }
    for ($i=1; $i <= (5 - $star); $i++) { 
        $total .= "<img src='../images/star_null.png'/> ";
    }
    if($star > 1 ){
        $reviews = " Reviews";
    }else{ 
        $reviews = " Review";
    }
    $total .= ($star) . $reviews;

    $total .="</div>";
    return $total;
}
```